# Elasticsearch Fails to Start Java Lang Illegal State Exception: No match found

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have been trying to get Elastic Stack to run for at least 2 days now, I have been given a project in school that requires me to use Elasticsearch 5.2.0 specifically (Logstash 5.2.0, and Kibana 5.2.0) I have not been able to get past installing Elasticsearch yet because it always fails to run the service. I have Java8 and Java11 (using Java8 for ES 5.2.0). The service always fails to run and anytime I check the error logs I keep getting the below:

```
[2022-11-17T20:37:58,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [F-2-m97] loaded module [reindex]
[2022-11-17T20:37:58,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [F-2-m97] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2022-11-17T20:37:58,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [F-2-m97] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2022-11-17T20:37:58,110][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [F-2-m97] no plugins loaded
[2022-11-17T20:37:58,779][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:645) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getControlGroups(OsProbe.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getCgroup(OsProbe.java:414) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.osStats(OsProbe.java:466) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsService.<init>(OsService.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.MonitorService.<init>(MonitorService.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:345) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:232) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$6.<init>(Bootstrap.java:241) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:241) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
[2022-11-17T20:37:58,788][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:645) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getControlGroups(OsProbe.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getCgroup(OsProbe.java:414) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.osStats(OsProbe.java:466) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsService.<init>(OsService.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.MonitorService.<init>(MonitorService.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:345) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:232) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$6.<init>(Bootstrap.java:241) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:241) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        ... 6 more
```

I have checked almost all online resource there is, with no luck! No one has a solution to this issue, at least not one I have been able to figure out... Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Maybe: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23218

Comment: Hey @JorgeCampos I found the same thread, but they did not suggest a generalized solution... They didn't suggest any solution at all. 
If you can find a solution on that thread that I can't find, can you kindly post it here?!

Comment: Hello Olaj, 5.2 has been end of life for a while now. I do think if possible the solution is to use a more up to date version of Elasticsearch

Comment: @Paulo beat me to it. Upgrade it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did that (used v8.5) and things worked fine, but that was not the requirement for the project and I had to revert because the dashboard, visualization, and search files provided to us only work on v5.2.0 (I am yet to try 5.2.2). Trying to get v5.2.0 working is a pain

Answer (score 0):

apparently the problem was not with the ELK stack version, but with the OS version (see [Elastic Support Matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix). I had to downgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 because ES 5.2.* works well on 16.04 but with some of its own bugs. Thanks for your help!